# How could I set bogus answers to 1 for the month, 1 for the day, and 2018 for the year?

Tags: java

// Here is my problem...

```
         while (doAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the details of a new event ...");
            System.out.println("Name: ");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            names[count] = name;
            if (mNum <= 12) && (day <= 31) && (year <=2018) {
            System.out.println("Month: ");
            mNum = sc.nextInt();
            months[count] = mNum;
            System.out.println("Day: ");
            day = sc.nextInt();
            days[count] = day;
            System.out.println("Year: ");
            year = sc.nextInt();
            years[count] = year;
            } else {
                (mNum = 1), (day = 1), (year = 2018);
            }
```

// User inputs y or n to determine if they wish to place more events

```
            System.out.println("Do you have another event?");
            count = count + 1;
            doAgain = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure on how to set a bogus month to January, for example if the user enters 13 for the month, it should set the month to January. And if a  day surpasses 31, then it should also be set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
(mNum = 1), (day = 1), (year = 2018);
```

Try:

```
mNum = 1;
day  = 1;
year = 2018;
```